# how to get the top 10 best selling product

Tags: apex

I need to get the top 10 products that has the most number of closed won opportunities. I have to create a report for it. How can i achieve this?
How can i get the product with the highest closed won opportunities? do i need to code it or it can be done with standard features?
thanks in advance and respect post

Answer (score 1):

Run an opportunity report, then group by product, and sum quantity (or whatever other metric you'd like, like sales price), which you can then sort in descending order. You can then place this report on a dashboard and limit to the top 10 items. There's no reason you'd need to write code for this.